# intro.js-react using onchange

Tags: reactjs, intro.js

I am new to intro.js-react and I am currently trying to execute a function at a specific step, however I am having trouble figuring out how to do so. I know there is an `onChange` prop that can be used with `Steps` but I am unsure of how implement it here.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, Tooltip, Button, } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Steps } from "intro.js-react";
import "intro.js/introjs.css";

const Tutorial = () => {

  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [initialStep, setInitialStep] = useState(0);

  const clickAction = () => {
    setEnabled(true);
  };

  const onExit = () => {
    setEnabled(false);
  };

  // Tutorial steps
  const steps = [
    {
      element: ".s1",
      intro: "Step 1",
    },
    {
      element: ".s2",
      intro: "Step 2",
    },
    {
      element: ".s3",
      intro: "Step 3",
    },
    {
      element: ".s4",
      intro: "Step 4",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Box>
      <Steps
        enabled={enabled}
        steps={steps}
        initialStep={initialStep}
        onExit={onExit}
      />

      <Tooltip
        ml="1rem"
        hasArrow
        label="Click for tutorial"
        fontSize="md"
        borderRadius="10px"
        aria-label="information"
      >
        <Button colorScheme="facebook" onClick={clickAction} ml="2rem">
          Tutorial
        </Button>
      </Tooltip>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Tutorial;
```

How would I be able to implement `onchange` so that I could execute a function at a certain step (example when step is at `.s2`)

I have tried examples from other posts however those approaches are related to intro.js, not intro.js-react.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you can use the `onChange` handler for this.

Per documentation the `onChange` handler receives two arguments

> Function (nextStepIndex, nextElement)

We can use the `nextStepIndex` to check if this index has a `element` value of `".s2"`. If it is the desired step we can execute a function. Something like this should work:

```js
<Steps
  enabled={enabled}
  steps={steps}
  initialStep={initialStep}
  onExit={onExit}
  onChange={(nextStepIndex) => {
    const isS2 = steps[nextStepIndex].element === ".s2";
    if (isS2) {
      console.log("it is s2");
      // here your function
    }
  }}
/>
```